# How can I do pagination with MongoDB ObjectId as key for Previous and Next button?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have pagination in my page with Previous and Next button.

If i click **Next** button, i am using following method,

```
db.test.find({'_id': {'$gt': '10th _id'}}).limit(10)
```

but don't know which method need to use when am clicking **Previous** Button also need to hide the **Previous** button in staring page and need to hide the **Next** button when i am in last page.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Store the current step in a variable and use `skip(10)` in MongoDB

```
db.test.find({'_id': {'$gt': '10th _id'}}).skip(variableName).limit(10)
```

For hiding the previous and next buttons you will have to check separately. The variable name will help you with that.

Comment: skip() method is very slow if i have more documents

Comment: do let me know if you find a solution.